# C# .net windows forms dialog next/previous buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dialog

In a C# .net windows forms application, I have a dialog window with the buttons "next" and "previous", and I want to "move to the next or previous page" according to what buttons the user pressed.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Just use a pre-written "wizard" library, don't re-implement the wheel. See here for options: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=wizard+winforms

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Panel` or `GroupBox` to wrap your `textboxes,labels and buttons`.
Then in your `Previous Page` and `Next Page` button, call your groupBox name.

```
groupBox.Hide();
```

and

```
 groupBox.Show();
```

will do the trick.

For example if you are calling your first page:

```
groupBox1.Show();
groupBoxOtherPage1.Hide();
groupBoxOtherPage2.Hide();
```

PS : You can do `Hide() and Show()` to panel also, actually all your form element, but grouping your element in container like `Panel or GroupBox` will be best.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of tool that you can use for Next and Previous step wizard. for example DevExpress Wizard Control.
But, if you want to go with the simple windows form application you need to follow some trick. Like take some panels and add it to your form. every panel should be placed on form and all panels location and size should be same and named it `panel0`, `panel1`, `panel2`, etc. and take three buttons `btnNext`, `btnPrevious` and `btnClose` and write some code to navigate that panels

```
int TotalPanelCount = 3;  //last index of panel will be 2
int _index = 0;
public int Index
{
  get { return _index; }
  set { 
    if (TotalPanelCount < 3)
        _index = value;
    else
        _index = TotalPanelCount - 1; 
    ChangeIndex();
    }
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Index++;
}
private void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Index--;
}
private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Close();
}

private void ChangeIndex()
{
    string _panelName = "penal" + Index.ToString();

    //Hide all visible panel
    var panels = (From Control cnt in this.Controls
                  Where cnt.getType().Name.Equals("Panel") &&
                  cnt.Name != _panelName && cnt.Visible == true
                  Select cnt).ToArray();
    foreach(Control cnt in panels)    
       cnt.Visible = false;

    //Displaying current panel
    Panel pnl = (Panel)this.Controls[_panelName];
    pnl.BringToFront();
    pnl.Visible = true;
}
```